# Socket.io multiple handlers for `on` listeners, like in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, socket.io

Express lets the developer chain multiple functions as handlers to a single route. From [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-handlers):

> More than one callback function can handle a route (make sure you
>    specify the next object). For example:
>
> ```js
> app.get('/example/b', function (req, res, next) {
>   console.log('the response will be sent by the next function ...')
>   next()
> }, function (req, res) {
>   res.send('Hello from B!')
> })
> ```

This is great if the developer wants to **make validations** before proceeding to the final function. That's why middlewares are a thing.

Socket.io, on the other hand, only accepts a single handler.

From [@types/socket.io](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/socket.io/index.d.ts#L231):

```js
on( event: string, listener: Function ): Namespace;
```

It means I can't have middlewares that are event-specific. I know about `io.use` for global middlewares, and there's an option to have a middleware per namespace too, but all I want is per-event.

---

## My workaround variations

#### Option 1: `try` and `catch` in *every* event handler.

```js
try {
  validateCurrentPlayer(socket);
} catch (e) {
  return handleFailedValidation(socket, e);
}
// ... rest of the code
```

**Pro:** readable. **Con:** super repetitive. It means that every relevant entry point with start with the same 5 lines of code that does exactly the same thing every time.

And if the "middleware" returns values, this is how it looks:

```js
let foo: Something;
try {
  [foo] = validateCurrentPlayer(socket);
} catch (e) {
  return handleFailedValidation(socket, e);
}
// ... rest of the code, use foo
```

#### Option 2: Common validation with conditional return

```js
const validation = validate(socket, () => validateCurrentPlayer(socket));
if (validation.error) {
    return;
}
const [foo] = validation.result;
```

This is `validate`:

```js
export function validate<T extends (...args: any) => any>(socket: Socket, func: T): {
    error: boolean;
    result: ReturnType<T>;
} {
    let result: ReturnType<T> = null;
    let error = false;
    try {
        result = func();
    } catch (error) {
        handleFailedValidation(socket, error);
    }

    return {
        result,
        error,
    };
}
```

As you can see it just wraps the `try` and `catch`.

**Pro:** non-repetitive. **Con:** Still X lines of code to be copy-pasted into a few handlers.

---

## I don't like these workarounds.

I'm desperately trying to find something similar to the approach of Express, So I could just conditionally call `next()` if the validation succeeded.

Do you know of any way to do it?

Thanks!